# Appending two audiofiles React Native

Tags: react-native, audio, ffmpeg, concatenation

I want to combine to wav files into one file. So file1 + file2 = file3.
I am currently looking into ffmpeg, but when I try to use concat it only returns a file with the length of the first file. The react native code that I use is:

```
RNFFmpeg.execute('-i "concat:' + path1 + '|' + pathOutput + '" -acodec copy ' + pathOutput2).then(result => console.log("FFmpeg process exited with rc " + result.rc));
```

Is my command wrong?

If you have a better solution for this please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Ffmpeg concat protocol does not work on mp4 files. It gives back the first file only. Concat demuxer does the job perfectly.

Below is the working code:

```
export const mergeAllRecordingsForVisit = async (filePaths) => {
  const textFile = await writeTextFileWithAllAudioFiles(filePaths)
  const outputPath = 'finalRecording.mp4'
  const command = `-f concat -safe 0 -i ${textFile} -c copy ${outputPath}`
  const result = await RNFFmpeg.execute(command)
}


const writeTextFileWithAllAudioFiles = async (filePaths) => {
  var fileContent = ''
  filePaths.forEach(path => {
    fileContent += `file '${path}'\n`
  });
  const filePath = 'audioList.txt'
  try {
    await RNFS.writeFile(filePath, fileContent, 'utf8')
    return filePath
  } catch (error) {
    return error
  }
}
```